# Store subscribe not working in external component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, observer-pattern

So technically I have 2 components, I dispatch event from 1st, I want detect this change in 2nd.
I did everything as in Redux docs about Store subscribing : https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribe. Unfortunatelly, it's not working for me.

This is my 1st react project.
(vue/x is better :] )

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import reducers from '../../reducers'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import {translate} from "../../actions";
import createStore from "../../createStore";

const store = createStore(reducers)

class Component1 extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        store.subscribe(() => console.log(1));
    }

    updateTexts(lang) {
        store.dispatch(translate(lang));
    }


    render() {
            this.dropdown = <Dropdown
            onChange={this.updateTexts}
            />

        return (
            <div className={"lang-switcher"}>
                 <div className={"select-lang"}>
                    {this.dropdown}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
     }
 }

export default Component1
```

---

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Animate} from 'react-animate-mount';
import createStore from "../../createStore";
import reducers from "../../reducers";

const store = createStore(reducers);

export default class Component2 extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        store.subscribe(console.log(2));
    }

    render() {
         return (
            <div className="box">
                {Something}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want that Component2 will detect state change done by Component1.
Reducer is working correctly, updates state after dispatching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a script Store.js, and import for each component.
When you use export, that will create a singleton from your export const:

Store.js

```
import reducers from '../../reducers'
import createStore from "../../createStore"
export default createStore(reducers)
```

and use as:

```
import store from "./Store";

/* REMOVE const store = createStore(reducers); */
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React, [you should be using the React-Redux library to handle interacting with the store](https://react-redux.js.org).

That said, it also looks like you're creating two different store instances, one in each component file.  So, Component 2 doesn't know about the store instance in Component 1's file.

Comment: I am using react-redux. So how can I make 1 store?

Comment: You're _not_ using React-Redux right now, at least not in those examples. You're not doing `import {connect} from "react-redux"` and using it anywhere.  As for the store, you normally call `createStore()` once, in your app's main entry point.  See the ["Configuring Your Store" Redux docs page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store) for examples.

Comment: If you're going to use libraries, you should read the documentation and follow their instructions.

Comment: Yeah, but it's weird. I used Vue which has one simple Vuex library.

Comment: React and Redux are not Vue and Vuex :)  They're similar, but different, and so they work differently.